# How to soft-delete records in entity with collection in asp.net core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, soft-delete

My issue here is that I can't soft-delete entities in a collection `SavePartnerRegistryResource`. those are my entities resources,

```
public class SavePatientsRegistryResource {
     public long? PatientFileId { get; set; }
     public SavePatientsRegistryResource () {
     Partners = new Collection<SavePartnerRegistryResource> ();
     }
}
public class SavePartnerRegistryResource {
    public string RecordId { get; set; }
    public long? PatientFileId { get; set; }
    public long? PartnerFileId { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

The way I do it is that I eagerly load my entities in my controller
and I user `automapper` to map from my resource to my entity. I handle my collection (add/remove) in the `AfterMap`,

```
.AfterMap((s, d) = >{
    foreach(PartnerRegistry partner in d.Partners.ToList()) {
    SavePartnerRegistryResource modelPartner = s.Partners.FirstOrDefault(c = >c.PatientFileId == partner.PatientFileId && c.PartnerFileId == partner.PartnerFileId);
    if (!s.Partners.Contains(modelPartner)) {
        d.Partners.Remove(partner);
    }
}
```

Removing the `SavePatientsRegistryResource` will soft delete the entity itself and the collection **BUT** removing from the collection `SavePartnerRegistryResource` will hard delete the record instead of mark it as soft-delete. both entities receive soft-delete property upon building the models.

What am I missing here?

my override saving method is,

```
public override Task < int > SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken =
default(CancellationToken)) {
        OnBeforeSaving();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }

private void OnBeforeSaving() {
    foreach(var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()) {
        if (!EntitiesToExclude().Contains(entry.Entity.ToString())) {
            switch (entry.State) {
            case EntityState.Added:
                entry.CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = false;
                break;
            case EntityState.Deleted:
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                entry.CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = true;
                foreach(var navigationEntry in entry.Navigations.Where(n = >!n.Metadata.IsDependentToPrincipal())) {
                    if (navigationEntry is CollectionEntry collectionEntry) {
                        foreach(var dependentEntry in collectionEntry.CurrentValue) { (Entry(dependentEntry)).State = EntityState.Modified;
                            (Entry(dependentEntry)).CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        var dependentEntry = navigationEntry.CurrentValue;
                        if (dependentEntry != null) { (Entry(dependentEntry)).State = EntityState.Modified;
                            (Entry(dependentEntry)).CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You're not isolating the collection entities to mark their state as `EntityState.Deleted`.  Everything in your code is setting state as `EntityState.Modified`.

Comment: I guess this happens in the `AfterMap`. I can't find a way to mark the state as `Deleted` in there

Comment: The Only way that I got it to work is by removing the `AfterMap`, ignoring mapping of the collection. after that I iterating over the collection "manually" and remove entities directly the collection and saving the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is,

Ignore the collection during mapping and I removed the collection
    modifications in `AfterMap`.

I created a `EqualityComparison` map using `AutoMapper.Collection`

```
CreateMap<SavePartnerRegistryResource, PartnerRegistry> ().EqualityComparison ((s, d) => s.PatientFileId == d.PatientFileId && s.PartnerFileId == d.PartnerFileId);
```

I map the collection in a separate `List`,

```
List<PartnerRegistry> patientPartnersModelDataList = mapper.Map<List<SavePartnerRegistryResource>, List<PartnerRegistry>> (model.Partners.ToList (), patient.Partners.ToList ());
```

Now I can get added/removed/modified entities as following,

```
IEnumerable<PartnerRegistry> partnerRegistryToRemoveList = patient.Partners.ToList ().Except (patientPartnersModelDataList);
IEnumerable<PartnerRegistry> partnerRegistryToAddList = patientPartnersModelDataList.Except (patient.Partners.ToList ());
IEnumerable<PartnerRegistry> partnerRegistryToUpdateList = patient.Partners.ToList ().Intersect (patientPartnersModelDataList.ToList ());
```

then I run `foreach` to iterate over each entity and I perform Add/Remove using the context rather than modifying the `collection`,

For updating, I update the collection instead from `partnerRegistryToUpdateList`